# browserify-middleware concat all files to single file

Tags: express, browserify

I've currently got a load of JavaScript files I'd like to concat (and minify for production), using express browserify-middleware (v2).

```
var browserify = require('browserify-middleware');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/scripts', browserify('app/public/scripts/src'));
app.use('/scripts/output.js', browserify('app/public/scripts/src/test.js'));
```

I can make requests to output.js like so:

```
<script src="/scripts/output.js"></script>
```

This works, but only for the single file... what do I do when there is multiple? I've tried:

```
app.use('/scripts/output.js', browserify('app/public/scripts/src'));
app.use('/scripts/output.js', browserify('app/public/scripts/src/'));
app.use('/scripts/output.js', browserify('app/public/scripts/src/**/*.js'));
app.use('/scripts/output.js', browserify('app/public/scripts/src/*.js'));
```

These either fail or throw a 404 not found.

The docs mention:

```
//provide browserified versions of all the files in a directory
app.use('/js', browserify('./client/dir'));
```

However, what am I supposed to call for this?

Thanks,